# issue in upgrading odoo11 to odoo13 via OpenUpgrade

Tags: migration, odoo-11, odoo-13

I'm trying to upgrade odoo11 to odoo13 via openupgrade, I know you can't directly upgrade odoo11 to odoo13, you have to upgrade odoo11 to odoo12 and from odoo12 upgrade to odoo13.
after I upgrade odoo11 to odoo13, I try to run odoo13 based on database odoo11 that I've upgrade to odoo13, but I've got error when I'm Login,

the error like this (let say this error_1)

```
 Could not get content for /web_clearbit/static/src/less/web_clearbit.less defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'.&NewLine;Could not get content for /account_reports/static/src/less/account_financial_report.less defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'.&NewLine;Could not get content for /stock_barcode/static/src/less/stock_barcode.less defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'.&NewLine;Could not get content for /stock_barcode_mobile/static/src/less/stock_mobile_barcode.less defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'.&NewLine;Could not execute command 'lessc'This error occured while compiling the bundle 'web.assets_backend' containing:&NewLine;    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss&NewLine;    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss&NewLine;    - /web/static/src/scss/bs_mixins_overrides.scss&NewLine;    - /web/static/src/scss/utils.scss&NewLine;    - /web/static/src/scss/primary_variables.scss&NewLine;    - /web_enterprise/static/src/scss/primary_variables.scss&NewLine;    - /web_editor/static/src/scss/web_editor.variables.scss&NewLine;    - /mail/static/src/scss/variables.scss&NewLine;    - /portal/static/src/scss/primary_variables.scss&NewLine;    - /account/static/src/scss/variables.scss&NewLine;    - /web_editor/static/src/scss/secondary_variables.scss&NewLine;    - /web_enterprise/static/src/scss/secondary_variables.scss&NewLine;    - /web/static/src/scss/secondary_variables.scss&NewLine;    - /web_editor/static/src/scss/bootstrap_overridden_backend.scss&NewLine;    - /web_editor/static/src/scss/...
```

and after I ignore that error , I see odoo UI is messed up  I check for the data , and I see the data from odoo11 is still there (not change).

another error that I've got is when I'm going to setting app, the error is like this (let say error_2)

```
Error context:
View `res.config.settings.view.form.inherit.mail.push`
[view_id: 360, xml_id: mail_push.res_config_settings_view_form, model: res.config.settings, parent_id: 244]
```

and after I get error_2 I can't go to another app (purchase, sale, inventory, etc), can you help  me how to solve this.